# One page with one table as only content, can I easily vertically align?

Tags: html, css

I've read all about the horrors of vertically aligning web page content for all browsers.  I have a landing page for a website with only one table on there, is there an easy way to align this in either html or css?

Many thanks!

Lynne

Comment: A few searches of your own here on SO would provide plenty of resources for you on this subject.

Comment: Can you create a sample fiddle or maybe just link the page in question?

Comment: If the width and height of table if fixed, you can center it by using CSS only. In case, you don't know it, you have to depend on javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you know the width and height of your table**

You can do it with just CSS. **[SEE THE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PPDW4/1/)**

```
table {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px; //divide the width by 2
  margin-top: -100px; //divide the height by 2
}
```

**But if you don't know the width and height of your table**

You have to use jQuery to calculate those values to center the table on the page.: **[SEE THE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PPDW4/)**

```
var w = $(window).width(), //browser window width
    h = $(window).height(), //browser windwo height
    $table = $('table'),  
    tw = $table.outerWidth(), //table width along with padding and border
    th = $table.outerHeight(); //table height along with padding and border

    $table.css({
        'top' : (h - th)/2 + 'px', //top: ..px will be calculated after subtracting table height from window height and dividing it by 2. 
        'left' : (w - tw)/2 + 'px' // Same goes for left: ..px
    });
```

Don't forget to apply `position: relative;` to your table since you are using top and left value which won't work if position: absolute or relative isn't provided.

Comment: Tried this like so

`table {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -500px;
  margin-top: -300px;
}`

But it's putting the table so far right and down that you have to scroll to see all of it.  Did I miss a step?

Comment: Any tips as to why the table is pushed far to the right and bottom?  I do have an image in the center than spans three rows, would that affect anything?

Comment: If your width and height of table is changing due to that image inside it, then you can either use the jquery that I have posted above. Or you can inspect the table element and learn how wide and big your table is, then you can apply the margin accordingly.